# Difference between standard Java SDK by Sun and Java development package by Apple

Tags: java, macos

I have run across these two options, what to install in my mac and still not well understand the difference between the "SDK provided by Sun" and the "Java for Mac Development Package".

Obviously, I do java programming, but "Java for Mac Development Package" downloaded from developer.apple.com only supports version up to 6 (they call 10.6 for some reason), while the one provided by Sun is of version 7.

Can someone, please, explain to me, from the perspectives of a Java developer: (1) What are the differences between the two? (2) which one should I install?

The only advantage I know from the apple's version is I can have access to the source code, while the one from Sun does not provide that, so when I need to look the the source code of Java in eclipse, I need the Apple's version.

Comment: 1- Generally, very little.  Originally, Apple was writing the core implementation (the part which supported the public APIs) as well as provided some additional APIs, but Apple decided it no longer wanted to support it handed (most) of the responsibility back to Oracle. 2- You should use the one that you need to do.  Generally speaking, if you want to put your app on the Apple App Store, you will probably need to use 7, as the old .app bundler is no longer supported and may "disappear" in the future and I'm unaware if the new .app bundler supports 6

Comment: (1) Java 8 has been out for some time. (2) The source to OpenJDK is available.

Comment: Thank guys. Great answers. Heard that OpenJDK is unstable. People faced "fatal errors" while using it, so they switched back to Oracle JDK. Do you know if we can access src for Oracke JDK 7 for OS X? I have access to Java src for Windows. Not sure if that is the same as src for mac though.